# Python calculator with order of operations?

Tags: python, string, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a python calculator that takes inputs like these:

```
>>> 2+2*3
```

or

```
>>> 3*45+2*52/3
```

or

```
>>> 1+21/7-14/2
```

And return their answers with **order of operations** in mind.
I am not allowed to use any modules and I get user inputs in one line, one string. And basically there is no limit on how many operations user can enter.

I tried to strip away my  operators and numbers like this:

```
userin=input()
operators=[]

numbers=userin.replace('+',' ').replace('-',' ').replace('*',' ').replace('/',' ').split()
for char in userin:
    if char=='+' or char=='-' or char=='*' or char=='/':
        operators.append(char)
```

But my brain has stopped after trying to do basic math with order of operations this weekend. Any help?

Comment: Can you use `eval` ?

Comment: You don't appear to have tried doing any kind of math at all.

Comment: You could use [the shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm), for example. Note that coding such a calculator isn't trivial, so you probably won't be able to come up with a correct algorithm on your first try.

Comment: you will have to write an expression parser for that

Comment: That's not the right way to do this.  You have to scan the string one character at a time.  As long as you get digits, you build up a number (`accum = accum * 10 + int(newdigit)`).  If it's not a digit, you have to use a stack to hold numbers and operators until you know it's safe to do an operation.

Comment: Do you consider the question answered, or do you need a way to do it without imports and builtins that do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has calculator built-in, check out

```
exec(f"print({input()})")
```

[image: Calculator in python - Colab]

Comment: Sorry, I know it's been a long time but I thought I marked your answer, cheers!